# How to target only numbers in a list containing both numbers and alphabets?

Tags: css, html, css-selectors, xhtml

Here is my list items:

```
<ul class="col2">
   <li>from $400</li>
   <li>from $1000</li>
   <li>sold out</li>
   <li>from $1400</li>
</ul>
```

Now what i want is that i want to format all the numbers ($200,$1000 and $1400) to the following:
**Droid Serif, bold, 36px, #1c1819**

and the words(from and sold out) to the following:
**open sans, bold, 22px, #726850**

Is there a way i can do it?

Comment: yes if you wrap the numbers in a their own tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With only HTML and CSS you will need an extra element, in this case I would recommend to use a `<span>`:

```css
.col2 li {
  font: bold 22px"open sans";
  color: #726850;
}
.col2 li span {
  font: bold 36px"Droid serif";
  color: #1c1819
}
```

```html
<ul class="col2">
  <li>from <span>$400</span></li>
  <li>from <span>$1000</span></li>
  <li>sold out</li>
  <li>from <span>$1400</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks. This came to my mind but i thought that there might be an easy or more direct way that i may not know of. Thanks anyways. Great help.

Comment: @vikrantnegi007 There might be a way with jQuery to dynamically select all prices, but you'll then still need to wrap it in an element to style it. So, imo, this is the easiest way. If my answer suits you, please mark it as answer, but hitting the v-mark on the left of it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the script that generates this html? The easiest way would be to add css classes accordingly and then set styling for them.

Comment: Actually not. I'm just practicing html and css from the scratch and this particular problem came.